# Why didn't Gazelle die when Merlin detonates the security chips?

Tags: plot-explanation, kingsman-the-secret-service

I was wondering why Gazelle (assistant of Valentine) in Kingsman: The Secret Service didn't die or her head didn't pop out when Merlin detonates the security chips whereas it was shown in some part of the movie that Gazelle has a scar on her neck that proves that Valentine put a security chip into it. I think the part where the scar was shown is when Valentine was introducing his newly invented sim card in the expo.

Comment: Why did you accept the one answer that doesn't point out that you mistook two characters?

Comment: Because that is beside the point. They all had a device implanted, even Valentine had one. The answer picked is the only ones that explains why they alone did not explode.

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski And why do you think they all had an implant at all?

Comment: Because the device was necessary in everyone he did not want dead. He put one in himself, any every other person in on it. Give me a reason why we should assume she did not have you?

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski I don't remember the movie completely right now, is this explained at some point? Or is this just a deduction along the same line as the accepted answer?

Comment: Is what explained? Everyone without the device was in grave danger because it was the only thing that could protect them from the phones.

Answer (score 11):

The woman at Valentine's press conference (where they notice that she has an implant) **is actually *not* Gazelle** but some other assistent of him, who I'd wager wasn't as close/important as Gazelle to warrant an exception from the implant. As you can see, she has a significantly different face and haircut (which Gazelle never changes throughout the movie):

[image]

In fact, we see her again at other points throughout the movie. For example, when Harry sees her carry the invitation for the church event while visiting Valentine at home (where he also sees Gazelle, so they can't be one and the same person). Another point is when Eggsy is greeted by her when arriving at Valentine's base and hands her his weapons.

[image]

When looking at [IMDb's credits](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2802144/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) I'd conclude that it is [Johanna Taylor](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm4935233/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t31) credited as *"Valentine's Assistent 1"* rather than [Sofia Boutella](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1154749/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t10)'s Gazelle.

Answer (score 7):

The assistant in question isn't Gazelle, she is in fact another assistant also featured in the scene where Galahad/Harry walks into Valatine's home and sees the women with the leaflet for the church.

Comment: That might be the case, but it can be inferred very reliably that she had a scar as well. They all needed the device implanted, even the mastermind.

Answer (score 2):

After the head exploding scene Valentine stated that he's not that stupid to implant an explosive version of the implant into himself. They both still needed the implant to be immune to the effects of the signal.

We can assume he did the same thing for his right-hand assistant Gazelle.

Comment: This answer isn't based on any evidence. Moreover it fails to point out that the original question contains a wrong assumption: the character shown to have a scar wasn't Gazelle.

Comment: @BCdotWEB to be fair the question doesn't have any evidence that Gazelle actually has an implant

Answer (score -1):

That woman in the expo wasn't Gazelle i dont think, just another politician

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE. Why do you think this? What makes it so? Please flesh out your answer which will make it better received on the site!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's Gazelle.

Comment: @Ricardo No, [it isn't](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36864/49).